# Passing Value of Text Field Between Views iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5

thanks for helping a novice.  I'm trying to use the value of a Text Field in SecondViewController.xib to set up a settings string in WebService.m.  I've included my code.  When I execute the application, my NSLog from WebService give me an output of "The test IP is: (null)"  The NSLog from SecondViewController.m is the value of the Text Field.  How do you pass the strIP to WebService.m correctly?  Using the example code would be very helpful.

SecondViewController.h:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

{
UITextField *ipAdd;

NSString *strIP;

}
@property (nontoxic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *ipAdd;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strIP;


-(IBAction)textchanged:(id)sender;

+(SecondViewController*)sharedIP;
```

SecondViewController.m:

```
-(IBAction)textchanged:(id)sender
{

strIP = ipAdd.text;
NSLog(@"the string in the text field is: %@", strIP);

}

+(SecondViewController*)sharedIP
{
static SecondViewController *sharedIP = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedIP = [[SecondViewController  alloc] init];
        });
return sharedIP;
}
```

WebService.m:

```
SecondViewController *IP = [SecondViewController sharedIP] ;
NSLog(@"The test IP is:  %@", IP.strIP);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify a value in a block, you need to use the `__block` type specifier on the variable type (sharedIP) so modifications in the block affect the value outside the block.

Also: every time you call +sharedIP, you set the value of the static to nil and only reset it the first time. Your design seems a bit odd... I'm not sure why you would ever want a static instance of a view controller, but I don't know what you're after. If you just want persistent data, see NSUserDefaults (which is cool because it persists over restarts). It might be better to create a static instance of a data container to persist your string value.

Good luck.

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for something like this!  The NSUserDefaults is the ticket. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check delegate of your textField that should be your SecondViewController.
2. Try the print the same value before you return. e.g. :

   +(SecondViewController*)sharedIP
   {
       static SecondViewController *sharedIP = nil;
       static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

   ```
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
   sharedIP = [[SecondViewController  alloc] init];
   });

   **NSLog(@"The test IP is:  %@", sharedIP.strIP);**

   return sharedIP;
   ```

   }

Might help

Cheers